# Steps to Simplify

Tags: self-learning, factoring

I am struggling to see how the following problem is simplified.  Can someone include any steps that may have been skipped?

Original Equation= $\frac{T(p-b)}{(p-b+q-a)}$

Simplified Equation= $T\times\frac1{1+\frac{(q-a)}{p-b})}$

Comment: Divide both numerator and denominator with $(p-b)$ and decompose into partial fractions.

Comment: @thanasissdr thank you for your help

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Dividing top and bottom by $p-b$ gives

$$\dfrac{p-b}{p-b+q-a}=\dfrac{\dfrac{p-b}{p-b}}{\dfrac{p-b+q-a}{p-b}}=\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{p-b}{p-b}+\dfrac{q-a}{p-b}}=\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{q-a}{p-b}}$$

Answer (score 0):

You have
$$
(p-b+q-a)=((p-b)+(q-a))=(p-b)\times\left( 1+\frac{q-a}{p-b}\right)
$$ thus, simplifying by $\color{red}{(p-b)} \neq 0$, gives
$$
\frac{T(p-b)}{(p-b+q-a)}=\frac{\color{red}{(p-b)}\times T }{\color{red}{(p-b)}\times\left( 1+\frac{q-a}{p-b}\right)}=\frac{T}{ 1+\frac{q-a}{p-b}}.
$$

Comment: @Amaziah You are welcome!